# How to redirect url using sef rewriting and .htaccess on Joomla 2.5?

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, joomla2.5, sef

I've already read everything i could find on this subject but I still can't redirect my new urls to the old ones !

I'm using Joomla 2.5.6, with Apache and the SEF works fine but the SEF-rewrite doesn't. The URL is actually well rewritten but it doesn't redirect me to the old URL.

I already did this manipulation on a Joomla 1.5 site and it worked fine by changing htaccess.txt to .htaccess and by editing configuration.php but it looks like something has changed on Joomla 2.5

Basically I want my new URL: mysite.com/page.html to redirect to the old one: mysite.com/index.php/page.html

I really need you help ! Thanks !

Comment: Please try to update your joomla installation. 2.5.6 is too old, you have to upgrade to 2.5.24 with the automatic updater. Based on your needs you don't need url rewrite to be opened as it will remove index.php from your url.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer emmanuel. I haven't upgraded to 2.5.24 yet because I have this message "Invalid login" when I try to upgrade it with both the automatic updater and by ftp. I gave 775 right to all concerned folders thow.

Comment: Try to add ftp details to: Global Configuration -> Server -> Ftp Settings. Add the update package (unziped) to /tmp directory and run upgrade from: Extensions -> Extension Manager -> Install from Directory.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this and I'll come back to you !

Comment: Thanks for the tip emmanuel, I upgraded to 2.5.24 by using the ftp method. But the "index.php" is still here ! Any idea ?

Comment: I tried setting URL rewritting to YES but I had the same error. So I switched it back to NO.

Comment: 4 steps to help you debug your issue: 
1. Users -> User Manager -> Options -> Allow User Registration: No / 
2. Extensions -> Module Manager (disable login plugin) / 
3. Templates -> Template Manager -> Switch to default template / 
4. Update .htaccess file with a fresh downloaded from joomla.org

Comment: I did these 4 steps but it didn't solve the problem. The 'Allow User Registration' was already set to YES, I disabled the login plugin (I had issues login back to my admin panel), I switched to the default template (but I work for a company that has its own template) and I updated .htaccess file with a fresh one. When should I swich SEF-rewriting to ON ? Do I need to switch it ? I'm a little panicked right now ^^. Thank you for you help emmanuel

Comment: After these steps try to enable Global Configuration -> Use URL rewriting. if it still doesn't work you have to check your server setup, there may be something wrong with apache.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help emmanuel. My problem is solved and it was actually something wrong with apache. I had to rename my joomla file (located at /etc/apache2/sites-available) with my domain name. I also uploaded a router.php file (at /components/com_virtuemart) I found on a forum, and now my SEF rewriting works perfectly !

Comment: Nice to hear that! You are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved and it was actually something wrong with apache. I had to rename my joomla file (located at /etc/apache2/sites-available) with my domain name. I also uploaded a router.php file (at /components/com_virtuemart) I found on a forum, and now my SEF rewriting works perfectly !